# Basic Authentication service called By Zuul

Tags: spring-security, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul

I'm Zuul as edge server. so all request pass by this edge server.
I have a micro-service A. all web services of A are protected by Basic Authentication.
How can we call the services of A b passing by Zuul proxy?
Should I add header for messages?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ideally the requester would have the token in the request.
If you want to have Zuul add the authentication token then you can create a ZuulFilter and use:

```
context.addZuulRequestHeader("Authorization", "base64encodedTokenHere");
```

Doing this would give open access to the services - which may not be wise.

Answer (score 8):

This is my Zuul filter:

```
public class BasicAuthorizationHeaderFilter extends ZuulFilter {


@Override
public String filterType() {
    return "pre";
}

@Override
public int filterOrder() {
    return 10;
}

@Override
public boolean shouldFilter() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public Object run() {

    RequestContext ctx = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
    ctx.getRequest().getRequestURL();
    ctx.addZuulRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + Utils.getBase64Credentials("user", "Token"));
    return null;
}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@Component
public class PreFilter extends ZuulFilter {
private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PreFilter.class);

@Override
public String filterType() {
    return "pre";
}

@Override
public int filterOrder() {
    return 1;
}

@Override
public boolean shouldFilter() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public Object run() {
    RequestContext ctx = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
    HttpServletRequest request = ctx.getRequest();
    ctx.addZuulRequestHeader("Authorization", request.getHeader("Authorization"));

    LOG.info("Parametres : {}", request.getParameterMap()
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .map(e -> e.getKey() + "=" + Stream.of(e.getValue()).collect(Collectors.toList()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList()));
    LOG.info("Headers : {}", "Authorization" + "=" + request.getHeader("Authorization"));
    LOG.info(String.format("%s request to %s", request.getMethod(), request.getRequestURL().toString()));
    return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please remove the unnecessary code in your answer and add a short explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can call (through Zuul) your service A like this :

```
https://login:password@zuulurl.com/serviceA
```

but firslty allow **AUTHORIZATION** header through Zuul for this specific service (route) with the property **sensitiveHeaders** in your properties file :

```
zuul.routes.serviceA.sensitiveHeaders=Cookie,Set-Cookie
```

or let it empty if you want to pass the Cookie headers too.

Here more informations about [headers through Zuul](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Edgware.SR3/multi/multi__router_and_filter_zuul.html#_cookies_and_sensitive_headers)

Answer (score 0):

Use zuul's sensitive header property with the blank value,

```
zuul.sensitiveHeaders=
```

Above property will do the trick but if you want to have filters for Cookie headers
 you can use that property with values,

```
zuul.sensitiveHeaders=Cookie,Set-Cookie
```

Answer (score 0):

This change is little tricky.

```
@Override
public int filterOrder() {
    return 1; // change the return value to more than 5 the above code will work.
}
```

try with the final code below:

```
@Component
public class PreFilter extends ZuulFilter {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PreFilter.class);

    @Override
    public String filterType() {
        return "pre";
    }

    @Override
    public int filterOrder() {
        return 10;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldFilter() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Object run() {
        RequestContext ctx = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
        HttpServletRequest request = ctx.getRequest();
        ctx.addZuulRequestHeader("Authorization", request.getHeader("Authorization"));
        return null;
    }
}
```