# How to consume basic-authentication protected Restful web service via feign client

Tags: spring-security, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix

Thank you for your time.
To make it simple, I created a example service like below:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class ComputeController {

    @GetMapping("/add")
    public int add(@RequestParam("left") int left, @RequestParam("right") int right) {
        return left + right;
    }
}
```

To protected this url, I config spring-security like this:

```
management.security.enabled=true
security.user.name=admin
security.user.password=admin
```

When I startup this service and access like this:

```
GET /add?left=100&right=11 HTTP/1.1
Authorization: ***** Hidden credentials *****
Host: localhost:7777
Connection: close
```

Everythis is going fine.

In other node, I created a "service-comsumer" by netflix feign. It's a Java Interface.

```
@FeignClient(name = "API-GATEWAY", path = "/compute-service", fallback = ComputeServiceCircuitBreaker.class)
public interface ComputeServiceClient {

    @RequestMapping(path = "/add", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Integer add(@RequestParam("left") Integer left, @RequestParam("right") Integer right);
}
```

But I DO NOT know how to config the request header "Authorization".

Any idea? Thanks again.

Comment: I found the answer.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35491581/basic-authentication-service-called-by-zuul?rq=1

Answer (score 58):

You need to create a FeignClient Configuration class, for example

```java
import feign.auth.BasicAuthRequestInterceptor;

@Configuration
public class FeignClientConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public BasicAuthRequestInterceptor basicAuthRequestInterceptor() {
         return new BasicAuthRequestInterceptor("admin", "admin");
    }
}
```

then in your `@FeignClient` annotation use this configuration file:

```java
@FeignClient(name="service", configuration = FeignClientConfiguration.class)
```

Comment: Using `@Configuration` here causes this bean to be applied to *all* `@FeignClient` and you do not need the `configuration =` part. If you remove `@Configuration` then this bean is ignored, and the `configuration =` part does nothing.

Comment: The correct way to do this (if you want it just on one specific `@FeignClient`) is to add `@Configuration` and then exclude it from `@ComponentScan` with `excludeFilters`

Comment: why would it be applied to all if `configuration` attribute is not used with `@FeignClient`.

Comment: @Ravik because it is picked up by component scan. For those confused by this (as I was) read [documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi_spring-cloud-feign.html#spring-cloud-feign-overriding-defaults)

Comment: Thanks, this works for me. One comment, be careful, use `feign.auth.BasicAuthRequestInterceptor`, not `org.springframework.http.client.support.BasicAuthenticationInterceptor`...

Answer (score 16):

As of october 2020, this works:

```
public class FeignClientConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public BasicAuthRequestInterceptor basicAuthRequestInterceptor() {
        return new BasicAuthRequestInterceptor("asdf", "asdf");
    }
}


@FeignClient(name = "thirdPartyClient", url = "ceva.com",
        configuration = FeignClientConfiguration.class)
public interface ThirdPartyClient {

    @GetMapping
    Response get();
}
```

Note, we don't annotate the configuration with @Configuration in order to not apply it to all requests.

Comment: this did not work for me when `FeignClientConfiguration` has in itself `@Value` properties

Comment: it works just fine even with Value properties. Anything you're doing to not make it work, is wrong.

`public Config(@Value("${asdf}") String asdf, @Value("${asdf") String asdf){}`
`